# are any of the windows 7 versions not developer friendly?

Tags: windows-7

Are any of the windows 7 versions not developer friendly?

i.e. maybe they can't handle IIS or sqlserver *shrugs*

Answer (score 3):

Comparison between versions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7_editions

More info: http://www.extremetech.com/article2/0,2845,2340431,00.asp

"Windows 7 will be available in six different editions, but only Home Premium and Professional will be widely available at retail. The other editions are focused at other markets, such as the developing world or enterprise use."

Comment: +1 Does not directly answer the question, but provides useful information and doesn't deserve a -1.

Answer (score 2):

You need at least Professional to use IIS. The Home versions do not include it.

I don't see any reason you couldn't install your own web server on a lesser version though.

SQL Server Express and Developer should work on pretty much any version by their very nature (except perhaps Starter) - they are specifically enabled to work on any SKU, this is why they exist :)

Answer (score 0):

Starter edition should be the only one that would offer any trouble.

Comment: Why does Starter Edition offer trouble to developers?

Comment: Actually, Home will also pose some problems. It comes without IIS7 (something that is not absolutely necessary but sometimes needed)

Answer (score 0):

Grab an MSDN utlimate edition!  Can't go wrong having more power than you need...can always get screwed by not having enough power!  Better to have and not need than need and not have.

Comment: I don't have MSDN access though?

Comment: Grab the RC from here (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dd353205.aspx?ITPID=mscomsc) but hurry as this offer ends the 20th of august!

Comment: The RC will start to expire before long, and after that you will have to reformat and install the retail version. And while the RC is fairly stable, it's not as good as it could be. This solution works for a few months at best, and you won't get any security updates either. It's just delaying the inevitable.

Comment: Regardless of purchasing a bright new shiny license of windows 7 or not...I suggest that you toss all your standard development installs into a VM and run it from an external hard drive.  Then regardless of how windows performs, or expires, you can keep your VM work environment intact.  Once things come back up on your OS side...you plug the VM back in and you are off and running again.

Answer (score 0):

Any of them should be fine, but the Professional, Enterprise, and Ultimate editions come with [XP Mode](http://lifehacker.com/5245396/set-up-and-use-xp-mode-in-windows-7), a fully licensed version of XP running in a VM, that can be used for apps that don't run under Vista. That could come in handy for some older programs.

**edit**

Also, the Home editions do not come with IIS according to [this](http://digitizor.com/2009/02/20/how-to-install-microsoft-iis-server-on-windows-7/)